# How to extract files not into public folder in Laravel, zipper

Tags: php, laravel, file, zip

How i can extract files from zip in `storage/app/anyFolder`, but not public?

```
$directoryName = strval(time()).rand(1000, 9999);
Storage::makeDirectory('temp/'.$directoryName, 0777);
$path = 'storage/app/temp/'.$directoryName;
$zipArchive = Zipper::make('storage/app/resources/'.$id.'.zip')->extractTo($path);
```

Zipper trying open archive in `storage/app/public/resources/$id.zip` and extract to `storage/app/public/temp/$directoryName`

How to open archive which is located in `storage/app/resources/$id.zip` and extract to `storage/app/temp/$directoryName`?

Comment: Are you calling `$zipArchive–>close()` at the end?

Comment: @NerijusGedrimas it return error :\ - Call to a member function close() on null

Answer (score 1):

You can press F9 inside [7zip](https://7zipguides.com/), you'll get two panes. In the first, you navigate to the archive you want to extract, and in the second you navigate to the folder where you want your files extracted. This will skip the temp folder step...

Answer (score 0):

you can change **root** value in config/filesystems.php

```
 'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Comment: I meant that the archive and the extracted files were not accessible from the browser. How to use Zipper with local driver?